# shell_exec function PHP with gcc does not create file

Tags: php, apache, gcc, compiler-construction, shell-exec

```
<?php
shell_exec('gcc -o b a.c');
$output = file_get_contents("./b");
echo $output;
?>
```

When I execute this php script on my Apache server it does not create any file named b. What should I do?

Comment: First - check permissions - i.e. if user, from which apache was launched, has execute permission for this command and write permission to produce it's output

Comment: How do I do that? @AlmaDoMundo

Comment: Look this one It works for me

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26954235/3956401