# Running a C program on linux server

Tags: php, c, linux, shell

Hi all I am new on server stuffs, correct me if I got any error underneath.

I had recently set up a linux server for user to upload their own file on it. User could access the server through a dedicated webpage, sign in, upload and restore any file on the server. The webpage contain simple html, css and php script.

Meanwhile I got a C program which can help to compress the size of files. The program is not a executable file yet, but a bunch of .c and .h file. I tried to MAKE all the file in Linux and implement the C program to the server, and wish to auto-compress the user uploaded file before it is stored in the server.

However I am not sure how to call the C program inside the webpage.... Appreciate for any advices and guidelines, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure.. but what you need is to execute C programs from a webpage..

Comment: If you need to execute you 'C' code from HTML. if it is so then you can use PHP to do so, it has **exec** [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), using this you can call gcc to run your C code

Comment: You could use `gzip` or `zip` if you'd like to compress the files that users upload.  Most Linux distributions have at least gzip.  Be aware that allowing users to upload anything to your server and compile it will be seen by some people as an invitation for cracking and conversion of your server into their server.

Comment: I am now using the exec function to achieve my goal, and will try to improve the security measurement afterward, thanks guy!

Answer (score 0):

If you using php then I would recommend `shell_exec` function,

```
shell_exec('gcc yourfile.c -o someobjectfile');

output=shell_exec('./someobjectfile');

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Comment: A couple of things: first, this will compile the file over and over, probably unnecessary after the first time;  also, this can be a **giant security hole** if the users are allowed to upload the content being compiled.  Neither are your fault, just something for the next reader to consider.

Comment: I know @Paul but as per his requirement this is my answer.